# How to print 'Italic' font style text using ZPL commands

Tags: thermal-printer, zpl, zpl-ii

I have a requirement of printing text in zebra and brother thermal printers in Italic formate using ZPL commands. I have done lot googling but I didn't get any clue to print text in Italic font style. Is there any way to print text in Italic font style in thermal printer using ZPL commands. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ZPL has no mechanism for rendering italic from its existing fonts.  To get italic, you must download an italic font.  Typically, you use the Zebra Utilities to download the font and then the `^A@` command to select the font for printing.

Comment: Thanks for response @MarkWarren. "you use the Zebra Utilities to download the font" according to this line where we need to download the font. Do we need to download the required font in printer?.

Comment: Yes.  The zebra utilities allow you to download fonts and images to be stored in each printer, which are then usable by your label formats.